# Node js Nested Loops On Async and Await

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, async-await

**My Question is How To Write Nested Loops In Node Js**

My Code Is

```
var result = db.data;
var FirstArray= new Array();
var SecondArray= new Array();
GetUserData();
async function GetUserData(){
    for (let info of result) {
         await getUserInfo(info);
    }
    res.send({status:"True", data: FirstArray, newdata:SecondArray  });
 }
    function getUserInfo(info){
        return new Promise(( resolve, reject )=>{
             UserModel.UserType.findOne({'_id': info.UserId }, usersProjection, function(err, UserData) {
                 if(err) {
                    res.send({status:"Fale", Error:err });
                    reject(err);
                 } else {
                        var data = UserData;
                        FirstArray.push(data);
                        GetUser();
                        async function GetUser(){
                           for (let newinfo of data ) {
                               await getnewUserInfo(newinfo);
                           }
                       }
                       function getnewUserInfo(newinfo){
                          return new Promise(( resolve, reject )=>{
                             UserModel.UserTypeNew.findOne({'_id': newinfo.UserId }, usersProjection, function(newerr, UserData) {
                               if(newerr) {
                                   res.send({status:"Fale", Error:newerr });
                                   reject(err);
                              } else {
                                  SecondArray.push(UserData)
                                 resolve();
                               }
                            });
                         });
                       }
                 }
             });
        });
     }
```

I will Get The First Loop Details Only How to Get Second Loop Details.

suggest Another Methods also.

Then which method is the best practice of nested loops.

Comment: If you have a working loop but want to improve it, this question would be better asked on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to get the 2nd loop details, it's not completely clear though. If that were the case it would be off-topic on Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.GetPostList = function (req, res) {
var SkipCoun = 0;
SkipCoun = parseInt(req.params.Limit) * 10;
QuestionsPostModel.QuestionsPostType.find({}, {}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, skip: SkipCoun, limit: 10 }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ status: "False", message: "Some error occurred while Find Following Users ." });
    } else {
        const GetUserData = (result) =>
            Promise.all(
                result.map(info => getPostInfo(info))
            ).then( result =>{ console.log(result);  res.send({ status: "True", data: result }) }
            ).catch(err => res.send({ status: "False", Error: err }));


        const getPostInfo = info =>
            Promise.all([
                UserModel.UserType.findOne({ '_id': info.UserId }, usersProjection).exec(),
                FollowModel.FollowUserType.count({ 'UserId': info.UserId }).exec(),
                RatingModel.QuestionsRating.count({ 'PostId': info._id, 'ActiveStates': 'Active' }).exec(),
                RatingModel.QuestionsRating.count({ 'UserId': req.params.UserId, 'PostId': info._id, 'PostUserId': info.UserId, 'ActiveStates': 'Active' }).exec(),
                AnswerModel.QuestionsAnwer.count({ 'PostId': info._id, 'ActiveStates': 'Active' }).exec(),
                AnswerModel.QuestionsAnwer.find({ 'PostId': info._id }, 'AnswerText UserId Date').exec()
            ]).then(data => {
                let UserData = data[0];
                let followCount = data[1];
                let ratingCount = data[2];
                let UserRating = data[3];
                let AnswerCount = data[4];
                let Answerdata = data[5];


                var AnswersArray= new Array();

               return GetAnsUserData();
                async function GetAnsUserData(){
                    for (let ansInfo of Answerdata) {
                        await getAnswerInfo(ansInfo);
                     }

                     let result = {
                        _id: info._id,
                        UserId: UserData._id,
                        UserName: UserData.UserName,
                        UserCategoryId: UserData.UserCategoryId,
                        UserCategoryName: UserData.UserCategoryName,
                        UserImage: UserData.UserImage,
                        UserCompany: UserData.UserCompany,
                        UserProfession: UserData.UserProfession,
                        Followers:followCount,
                        PostTopicId: info.PostTopicId,
                        PostTopicName: info.PostTopicName,
                        PostDate: info.PostDate,
                        PostText: info.PostText ,
                        PostLink: info.PostLink,
                        PostImage: info.PostImage,
                        PostVideo: info.PostVideo,
                        RatingCount: ratingCount,
                        UserRating: UserRating,
                        AnswersCount: AnswerCount,
                        Answers: AnswersArray,

                    };
                    return result;
                  }

                  function getAnswerInfo(ansInfo){
                    return new Promise(( resolve, reject )=>{
                        UserModel.UserType.findOne({'_id': ansInfo.UserId }, usersProjection, function(err, AnsUserData) {
                            if(err) {
                                res.send({status:"Fale", Error:err });
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                FollowModel.FollowUserType.count({'UserId': AnsUserData._id}, function(newerr, count) {
                                    if(newerr){
                                        res.send({status:"Fale", Error:newerr });
                                        reject(newerr);
                                    }else{
                                        var newArray = [];
                                        newArray.push( {
                                                        _id: ansInfo._id,
                                                        UserId: AnsUserData._id,
                                                        UserName: AnsUserData.UserName,
                                                        UserCategoryId: AnsUserData.UserCategoryId,
                                                        UserCategoryName: AnsUserData.UserCategoryName,
                                                        UserImage: AnsUserData.UserImage,
                                                        UserCompany: AnsUserData.UserCompany,
                                                        UserProfession: AnsUserData.UserProfession,
                                                        Followers: count,
                                                        Date: ansInfo.Date,
                                                        PostId: ansInfo.PostId,
                                                        PostUserId: ansInfo.PostUserId ,
                                                        AnswerText: ansInfo.AnswerText
                                                    }
                                        );
                                        AnswersArray.push(newArray[0]);
                                        resolve(newArray[0]);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }


            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })

         GetUserData(result);

    }
});
};
```

Finally I will Get The Solution

**Thanks To All**

Answer (score 1):

Since mongoose should return promises you don't need new Promise. You can use map to map data into promises and then use `Promise.all` to wait for them while they all simultaneously execute. Your current code executes queries one by one (only executes the next if current is finished). This is not needed and very slow.

So you can map `db.data` to `[[first,second],[first,second],...]`. I don't map results of `findOne` since that should not return an array and find it strange that `something of resultOfFindOne` actually works because findOne should return one document or null.

Both `UserModel.UserType.findOne` and `UserModel.UserTypeNew.findOne` try to find one record by `_id` and both use the same `_id` so there is no need to do UserType query then when that comes back do the UserTypeNew query, you can just use `info.UserId` for both queries.

```
const GetUserData = (result) => 
  Promise.all(
    result.map(info=>getUserInfo(info))
  ).then(
    results=>{//results should be [[first,second],[first,second],...]
      let [FirstArray,SecondArray] = results.reduce(
        ([allFirst,allSecond],[first,second])=>
          [allFirst.concat([first]),allSecond.concat([second])],
        [[],[]]
      );
      res.send({ status: "True", data: FirstArray, newdata: SecondArray })
    }
  ).catch(
    err=>
      res.send({status:"Fale", Error:err })
  );
const getUserInfo = info =>
  //mongoose can return promises, no need to convert callback api to promise:
  //http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html
  Promise.all([
    UserModel.UserType.findOne({ '_id': info.UserId }, usersProjection).exec(),
    UserModel.UserTypeNew.findOne({ '_id': info.UserId }, usersProjection).exec()
  ]);
//when using const the function is not hoisted so you can't call a function
//  before it was declared.
GetUserData(db.data);
```

If you are using an older version of mongoose (not 5.xxx) you may still need to convert the callback based api to promises, it would look a bit like this:

```
const asPromise = object => fn => args =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      fn.apply(
        object,
        args.concat([
          (...result)=>
            (result[0])//first argument of callback is error
              ? reject(result[0])//reject with error
              : resolve(result.slice(1,result.length))//resolve with result(s)
        ])
      )
  );

const newUserType = asPromise(UserModel.UserTypeNew);
const userType = asPromise(UserModel.UserType);

//making a query with callback but convert it to promise
newUserType(UserModel.UserTypeNew.findOne)([
  { '_id': info.UserId }, usersProjection
]).then(//this will resolve as array, only need first item
  ([result])=>result
);    

userType(UserModel.UserType.findOne)([//note that I'm not passing UserModel.UserTypeNew.findOne
  { '_id': info.UserId }, usersProjection
]).then(//this will resolve as array, only need first item
  ([result])=>result
);
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer. i will try the first method but i am not get my exact result! in your first method:   ** secoundArray how to again the loop and get new results of ** My New Question Is [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597193/node-js-nested-loop-results-finally-push-to-single-array ]