# node js nested loop results finally push to single array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, mongodb-query

i will get the Array of Answers

but how to get the Answered users info;

the flow is Get **List of Posts**, **Post User Info**, **Post User Followers Count**, **Post Likes Count**, Login User Liked The Post **True or False**, 
**Answers**, **Answered User Info** and **Answered User Followers Count**

```
exports.GetPostList = function(req, res) {
    var SkipCoun = 0;
    SkipCoun = parseInt(req.params.Limit) * 10;
     QuestionsPostModel.QuestionsPostType.find({}, {} , {sort:{createdAt : -1}, skip: SkipCoun, limit: 10  }, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).send({status:"False", message: "Some error occurred while Find Following Users ."});
        } else {
                const GetUserData = (result) =>
                    Promise.all(
                        result.map(info => getPostInfo(info))
                    ).then(
                        results => {
                            let [UserInfo, UserFollowers, PostRatingCount, UserRatedCount, AnswersCount, AswersArray ] = 
                            results.reduce(([allOne, allTwo, allThree, allFour, allFive, allSix ], [one, two, three, four, five, six]) => 
                            [allOne.concat([one]), allTwo.concat([two]), allThree.concat([three]), allFour.concat([four]), allFive.concat([five]), allSix.concat([six])], [ [], [], [], [], [], [] ]);
                            res.send({ status: "True", UserInfo: UserInfo, UserFollowers: UserFollowers, PostRatingCount: PostRatingCount, UserRatedCount: UserRatedCount, AnswersCount:AnswersCount, AswersArray:AswersArray })
                        }
                    ).catch(err => res.send({ status: "Fale",Error: err}) );


                const getPostInfo = info =>
                    Promise.all([
                        UserModel.UserType.findOne({'_id': info.UserId }, usersProjection).exec(),
                        FollowModel.FollowUserType.count({'UserId': info.UserId}).exec(),
                        RatingModel.QuestionsRating.count({'PostId': info._id , 'ActiveStates':'Active' }).exec(),
                        RatingModel.QuestionsRating.count({'UserId': req.params.UserId, 'PostId': info._id, 'PostUserId': info.UserId, 'ActiveStates':'Active'}).exec(),
                        AnswerModel.QuestionsAnwer.count({'PostId': info._id , 'ActiveStates':'Active' }).exec(),
                        AnswerModel.QuestionsAnwer.find({ 'PostId':info._id }, 'AnswerText UserId Date' ).exec()
                    ]);

            GetUserData(result);

        }
     });
    };
```

How to Get The Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you formed the array, and you are passing it inside `Promise.all()` .
and you just need the data.

`Promise.all()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

see  Below Code (we can just do as promise `.then()` and `.catch()`):

```
exports.GetPostList = function (req, res) {
    var SkipCoun = 0;
    SkipCoun = parseInt(req.params.Limit) * 10;
    QuestionsPostModel.QuestionsPostType.find({}, {}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, skip: SkipCoun, limit: 10 }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ status: "False", message: "Some error occurred while Find Following Users ." });
        } else {
            const GetUserData = (result) =>
                Promise.all(
                    result.map(info => getPostInfo(info))
                ).then(
                    results => {
                        let [UserInfo, UserFollowers, PostRatingCount, UserRatedCount, AnswersCount, AswersArray] =
                            results.reduce(([allOne, allTwo, allThree, allFour, allFive, allSix], [one, two, three, four, five, six]) =>
                                [allOne.concat([one]), allTwo.concat([two]), allThree.concat([three]), allFour.concat([four]), allFive.concat([five]), allSix.concat([six])], [[], [], [], [], [], []]);
                        res.send({ status: "True", UserInfo: UserInfo, UserFollowers: UserFollowers, PostRatingCount: PostRatingCount, UserRatedCount: UserRatedCount, AnswersCount: AnswersCount, AswersArray: AswersArray })
                    }
                    ).catch(err => res.send({ status: "Fale", Error: err }));


            const getPostInfo = info =>
                Promise.all([
                    UserModel.UserType.findOne({ '_id': info.UserId }, usersProjection).exec(),
                    FollowModel.FollowUserType.count({ 'UserId': info.UserId }).exec(),
                    RatingModel.QuestionsRating.count({ 'PostId': info._id, 'ActiveStates': 'Active' }).exec(),
                    RatingModel.QuestionsRating.count({ 'UserId': req.params.UserId, 'PostId': info._id, 'PostUserId': info.UserId, 'ActiveStates': 'Active' }).exec(),
                    AnswerModel.QuestionsAnwer.count({ 'PostId': info._id, 'ActiveStates': 'Active' }).exec(),
                    AnswerModel.QuestionsAnwer.find({ 'PostId': info._id }, 'AnswerText UserId Date').exec()
                ]).then(data => {
                    let userData = data[0];
                    let followCount = data[1];
                    let ratingCount = data[2];
                    let ratingCountBy_postId = data[3];
                    let answerCount = data[4];
                    let answers = data[5];
                    // now you may need to construct some object or something and pass data as you required.
                    let result = {
                        user: userData,
                        follow_count: followCount,
                        rating_count: ratingCount,
                        rating_countBy_postId: ratingCountBy_postId,
                        answer_count: answerCount,
                        answers: answers
                    };

                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })


                    GetUserData(result);

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Bro i Get the Solution

Comment: @kathir if this answer helps, please approve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.GetPostList = function (req, res) {
var SkipCoun = 0;
SkipCoun = parseInt(req.params.Limit) * 10;
QuestionsPostModel.QuestionsPostType.find({}, {}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, skip: SkipCoun, limit: 10 }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ status: "False", message: "Some error occurred while Find Following Users ." });
    } else {
        const GetUserData = (result) =>
            Promise.all(
                result.map(info => getPostInfo(info))
            ).then( result =>{ console.log(result);  res.send({ status: "True", data: result }) }
            ).catch(err => res.send({ status: "False", Error: err }));


        const getPostInfo = info =>
            Promise.all([
                UserModel.UserType.findOne({ '_id': info.UserId }, usersProjection).exec(),
                FollowModel.FollowUserType.count({ 'UserId': info.UserId }).exec(),
                RatingModel.QuestionsRating.count({ 'PostId': info._id, 'ActiveStates': 'Active' }).exec(),
                RatingModel.QuestionsRating.count({ 'UserId': req.params.UserId, 'PostId': info._id, 'PostUserId': info.UserId, 'ActiveStates': 'Active' }).exec(),
                AnswerModel.QuestionsAnwer.count({ 'PostId': info._id, 'ActiveStates': 'Active' }).exec(),
                AnswerModel.QuestionsAnwer.find({ 'PostId': info._id }, 'AnswerText UserId Date').exec()
            ]).then(data => {
                let UserData = data[0];
                let followCount = data[1];
                let ratingCount = data[2];
                let UserRating = data[3];
                let AnswerCount = data[4];
                let Answerdata = data[5];


                var AnswersArray= new Array();

               return GetAnsUserData();
                async function GetAnsUserData(){
                    for (let ansInfo of Answerdata) {
                        await getAnswerInfo(ansInfo);
                     }

                     let result = {
                        _id: info._id,
                        UserId: UserData._id,
                        UserName: UserData.UserName,
                        UserCategoryId: UserData.UserCategoryId,
                        UserCategoryName: UserData.UserCategoryName,
                        UserImage: UserData.UserImage,
                        UserCompany: UserData.UserCompany,
                        UserProfession: UserData.UserProfession,
                        Followers:followCount,
                        PostTopicId: info.PostTopicId,
                        PostTopicName: info.PostTopicName,
                        PostDate: info.PostDate,
                        PostText: info.PostText ,
                        PostLink: info.PostLink,
                        PostImage: info.PostImage,
                        PostVideo: info.PostVideo,
                        RatingCount: ratingCount,
                        UserRating: UserRating,
                        AnswersCount: AnswerCount,
                        Answers: AnswersArray,

                    };
                    return result;
                  }

                  function getAnswerInfo(ansInfo){
                    return new Promise(( resolve, reject )=>{
                        UserModel.UserType.findOne({'_id': ansInfo.UserId }, usersProjection, function(err, AnsUserData) {
                            if(err) {
                                res.send({status:"Fale", Error:err });
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                FollowModel.FollowUserType.count({'UserId': AnsUserData._id}, function(newerr, count) {
                                    if(newerr){
                                        res.send({status:"Fale", Error:newerr });
                                        reject(newerr);
                                    }else{
                                        var newArray = [];
                                        newArray.push( {
                                                        _id: ansInfo._id,
                                                        UserId: AnsUserData._id,
                                                        UserName: AnsUserData.UserName,
                                                        UserCategoryId: AnsUserData.UserCategoryId,
                                                        UserCategoryName: AnsUserData.UserCategoryName,
                                                        UserImage: AnsUserData.UserImage,
                                                        UserCompany: AnsUserData.UserCompany,
                                                        UserProfession: AnsUserData.UserProfession,
                                                        Followers: count,
                                                        Date: ansInfo.Date,
                                                        PostId: ansInfo.PostId,
                                                        PostUserId: ansInfo.PostUserId ,
                                                        AnswerText: ansInfo.AnswerText
                                                    }
                                        );
                                        AnswersArray.push(newArray[0]);
                                        resolve(newArray[0]);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }


            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })

         GetUserData(result);

    }
 });
};
```

Finally I get The Answer 
 **Thanks To ALL**